# CMD BAT how to find out and rename the file

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder named `1830AE16C excel`

I want to use `1830AE16C` to rename the files in this folder.

(Before)

```
1_1234AE16C
2_5559AE15C
4_1000AE16E_pay
```

(After)

```
1_1830AE16C
2_1830AE16C
4_1830AE16C_pay
```

I have tried this:

```
@echo off

Setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for %%I in (.) do set CurrDirName=%%~nxI

   SET Replace=%CurrDirName: DOC=%
   ECHO %Replace%     

Set /p Pattern="Old name: "


For %%a in (*%Pattern%*.*) Do (
    Set "File=%%a"
    Ren "%%a" "!File:%Pattern%=%Replace%!"
)
```

How to omit the step of ask to input the text to find?

Comment: You linked to a picture of text describing your requirement? Really??

Comment: You put no effort in typing in a good and clear question. How much effort do you expect others to put in solving it?

Comment: dont know why i cant post all the text.  So i upload it by photo.

Comment: i have edit the question.

Comment: Please edit the question and paste in the code you have tried, include any error messages, describe what it does, describe what it should be doing.

Comment: Pasted. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

I rewrote your script a bit. It doesn't use variables any more, so there is no need for delayed expansion:

```
@echo off
for /d %%I in (*) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,*" %%A in ("%%I") do (
    Echo Foldername: %%I
    Echo First part: %%A
    Echo Secnd part: %%B
    for %%F in ("%%I\*") do (
      Echo Filename:   %%F
      for /f "tokens=1,2,* delims=_" %%X in ("%%~nxF") do (
        if "%%Z"=="" (
          ECHO ren "%%F" "%%X_%%A"
        ) else (
          ECHO ren "%%F" "%%X_%%A_%%Z"
        )
      )
    )
  )
)
```

I inserted some `Echo` lines for troubleshooting/showing what happens.
I also disabled the `ren` commands with `ECHO` for security reasons. Please analyze the output, if it's exactly what you want, before actually enabling them.